# Where does Rest API of WordPress perform the query to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress, rest

We use WP Rest API 2 extensively, especially for retrieving projects to feed a mobile app. 
We really love this system but on a particular installation we have problems with one project invalidating the call.
So, for example, this call http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/projects?per_page=100&page=1 gets invalidated by a particular project when we try to publish it. 
The problem is that I receive only an empty response and not even an error by Postman. The call has a 200 code (success) but it is an empty JSON.

My question: where should I echo the actual DB query in the rest API code? My idea is to replicate this query in the MySQL environment to be able to debug the situation. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming projects is a custom post type, you likely did not specify the rest api argument in your register_post_type function for projects.

You likely need to add this:

`'show_in_rest' => true'`

Once that is in your function, the rest API should return data instead of an empty response.